# Find corner points on a distorted image

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a CV system which should find position of reflective points on a flat board no matter from which angle the camera is looking at the board. 
I have put reflective points on the corners of the board as well to make the task easier.
So far I've sucessfully find coordinates of all the points as camera see it, but now I need to ge geometry correction so that new coordinates will not depend on the camera position (I want to calculate coordinates related to the corners of the board).

How can I find corner points of the board in Python?
I can't just use min/max as you can find in this example it doesn't work on all perspective distorted images.

Here are the points:

```
[[709, 890], [194, 881], [360, 695], [532, 591], [284, 468], [599, 389], [359, 258], [487, 252], [238, 158], [706, 154]]
```

---

An example of the annotated picture

[image: an example of the annotated picture]

Answer (score 0):

You say you have markers on the corners of a flat board, if you can also define the size of the board, you now have the 3d coordinates of 4 points. 
You could then explore the Perspective-n-Point algorithm to solve the pose of the board relative to the camera. You will also need to calibrate your camera to do this.
OpenCV has a python interface and provides functions to calibrate a camera, and solve PnP.

This is all quite a big subject - a good starting point are the openCV tutorials [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/db7/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html).

Come back as you work through specific areas of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this is another way to do it. My plan was to correct perspective using  cv2.getPerspectiveTransform and then apply cv2.warpPerspective. In ether case I need to define 4 corners of the board among all reflective points, this is the problem for now. I will try to make corner fiducials bigger so I can separate them by size.